# How do I compare the runtime of two parts of MPI code?

Tags: c, mpi

I have an assignment to apply matrix multiplication with vectors in 2 ways. The first is column-wise and the second row-wise. I implemented them in different cpp files, now I want to combine them to the same file. I tried to do it like this:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{
    int myId, Numofpoc,
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Numofpoc);       
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myId);

    // here column wise code 
    MPI_Finalize();
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Numofpoc);       
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myId);

    // here row wise code 
    MPI_Finalize();

    //then here I compare the time of each way
}
```

However, when I run it from the command line, the output of column-wise printed successfully, but the row-wise made the program stop working. If any one knows the solution to this problem or how I can make 2 regions in MPI, can you help me?

Comment: Is there a reason you absolutely have to use `MPI_Finalize()` and re-use `MPI_Init(...)`? Why can't you get rid of those and simply run the two one after the other (perhaps in separate function calls to differentiate the two methods) and time them?

Comment: I thought of that but i think this will make a conflict between them as the 2 ways use the same concept  of send and receive the difference it that in column wise i send columns to the process but in row wise i send rows 
so i want to re-use MPI_Init(...)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "conflict between them". If the two codes would work separately exactly as you intended, then simply putting the two of them together should not cause any issues. `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` don't care whether you are sending column-wise or row-wise, that is up to you to figure out.

Comment: okay i will try that , thanks so mush for you help .

Answer (score 1):

MPI doesn't allow you to make more than one call to `MPI_INIT` or `MPI_FINALIZE` in a single application. Those calls are only there to give the MPI library a chance to initialize itself by setting up internal data structures, connections, etc. Calling the functions more than once would just cause things to act strangely since the data structures/connections have already been set up once.

You don't need to worry about multiple parts of your applications interfering with each other. As long as you match up your sends and receives correctly, there's no reason that communication from one part of your program would intermingle with communication from another part. You should be doing that anyway as it's invalid code to have more sends than receives or vice versa.

Also, one thing you never actually addressed in your question body is what you asked in the title: "How do you time two parts of your MPI code". MPI provides the function `MPI_WTIME` that gives you a simple, portable way to get a timestamp that you can use to time different chunks of code. You could use it like this:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{
    int myId, Numofpoc;
    double start, stop, column_time, row_time;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Numofpoc);       
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myId);

    start = MPI_Wtime();
    // here column wise code
    stop = MPI_Wtime();
    column_time = stop - start;

    start = MPI_Wtime();
    // here row wise code
    stop = MPI_Wtime();
    row_time = stop - start;

    //then here I compare the time of each way
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: I understand now , i think i wrote the wrong title i asked about  how to handle the two programs not the time i already know the time 
here is my logic after edit
http://pastebin.com/JXtG7j91